# WordPress theme JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.notifyDefaults is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to develop my first theme. Im using a ready made HTML5 template and convert it to a wordpress theme.

However, I am having some trouble with Javascript. The HTML5 template uses jQuery scripts for animating it's menu etc. I have enqued the scripts and styles from the theme and they are mostly (!) working . However, in order to get them to work i had to search and replace all `$` with `jQuery` – my understanding is that to avoid conflicts wordpress wont allow `$`.

Some of the javascript functions arent working and im not entirely sure why. The console is saying `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.notifyDefaults is not a function`. Does anybody have any experience of this or knowledge about why this is happening?

Thanks in advance for any replies

I've put the page [here](http://wordpress-109470-361781.cloudwaysapps.com/) to replicate the error.

Comment: I cann call the function on your website, console returns:  (e){return i=t.extend(!0,{},i,e)} Are you calling the method to early - while jQuery isn;t loaded yet?

Comment: can you post your code here instead of redirecting to other pages ? the script part which you have included in your page

Comment: The order of the scripts are important when they are loaded. `$` and `jQuery` are basically same.  i think you were looking for this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: you need to load the file vendors.bundle.js before the scripts.bundle.js because the function is only defined in him...

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In order to troubleshoot i have now modified it so that rather than enquing the JS files in functions.php, i am calling them directly in the footer.php file. They are loading in exactly the same place and order as in the theme html5 template - see source [here](http://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/index.php?page=index&demo=demo5), but now im getting different javascript errors. I really cant work out why this is happening. Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Thanks.